# Why is sed changing permissions of a file on a cifs mounted share?

Tags: sed, permissions, samba, cifs, smb

I have an Arch linux machine that uses the following fstab entry to mount a share:

```
//192.168.3.1/Documents        /mnt/  cifs    credentials=/home/tal/.smbcredentials,rw,x-systemd.automount,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0600,dir_mode=0700,uid=tal 0 0
```

The server that is sharing the folder is a Windows server, and the partition the shared folder is on is NTFS.

Using the above fstab entry, the share mounts at boot just fine. As expected, all files at `/mnt/` appear to be owned by 'tal' and have the permissions 0600. Newly created files under /mnt are also owned by tal (whether they are created by root or tal), and have the 0600 permissions, as expected.

The problem is that if I have a file under /mnt:

```
-rw------- tal root 1000 test.txt
```

and I run this on it:

```
sed -i -e '1,2d' test.txt
```

to delete the first 2 lines, the 2 lines are deleted, but the file's permissions change to:

```
-r-------- tal root 1000 test.txt
```

Why is sed changing the file permissions? Looking at the inode of test.txt, I can tell that sed's `-i` option recreates the file with the new content rather than modifying the file, but that shouldn't really matter - all newly created files under `/mnt` should get the 0600 permissions.

As a test, I modified the same file with vim and checked the inodes too. Vim also recreates the file in place rather than modifying it, but when vim does it, the permissions remain as 0600.

Comment: Is it perhaps related to this [Configure CIFS mount point permissions](http://superuser.com/questions/345457/configure-cifs-mount-point-permissions) - more specifically, to CIFS Unix extensions and the `nounix` flag?

Comment: what's your `umask`?  `vim` is probably "smart" enough to replicate the perms of the original file.  `sed` doesn't, with perms on created files being set automatically by the user's `umask`.  BTW, see the `mount.cifs` man page - `file_mode` and `dir_mode` only apply if the server does **not** support the CIFS Unix Extensions.  Note also that permissions can be set in the share defintion on the server.

Comment: Adding 'nounix' flag to fstab didn't help. I'm not sure, but I would guess that samba only supports unix permissions if the shared folder is on a unix-partition (ext2, ext3, ext4, etc). In my case, it's on an NTFS partition, which has no unix permissions for samba to disable, so it makes sense to me that nounix wouldn't be necessary. My umask is 0022, which should make new files 644, but it doesn't - new files get made with permissions set by file_mode in my case, which makes sense. The file_mode option I use definitely changes the apparent file permissions on the mounted share.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure it's related: I remember AD users have an option to specify "Main group" in user membership "if you have mac clients or posix apps"

Comment: Sorry for the noise. I understand and agree a down-vote is better than no-opinion. As this was my first post here at U&L.SE and I didn't see the green check I use to see at askubuntu, I thought this question didn't already get a good answer and I just wanted to give a possible track for anyone skilled enough with both Lunix & MS to dig further.